# can not resolve symbol FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1' is set

with compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1' - everything is fine

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.techery:properratingbar:+'
    compile 'com.github.zagum:Android-SwitchIcon:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-intro:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Comment: You need to include the relevant error messages or an example of how it is failing within your question, Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you also put dependency in project gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-rc1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

and in app build gradle file put these two dependency

app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0' //new version 12.0.1
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and Gson file then rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

I found problem.
In my service exists

```
@Override
    public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    }
```

In 12 version this method marked as final. I removed **handleIntent** and everything becomes fine. But why does it tell me that service not visible ?..